# Convert a string into a two-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

So I was trying to do a maze and wanted to transform the maze into a two-dimensional array so it would be easier to manipulate, but I didn't really succeed. The best I've done is a list of string with the following :

```
map = """
OOOOOOOOOO
O O    O O
O . OO   O
O O O   XO
O OOOO O.O
O O O    U
O OOOOOO.O
O O      O
O O OOOOOO
O . O    O
OOOOOOOOOO
"""
map = [i for i in map.splitlines()]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try `[list(i) for i in map.splitlines()]`.

Comment: Just an FYI, with your `map` string as it's currently written, you'll have an empty list at position 0 (since multi-line strings preserve all newlines). If you don't want this, you can add a `\\`` to skip the first newline -> `map = """\\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[splitlines()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_splitlines.htm) returns a list of strings. Each string being a line.

So when you call it on your example, it returns a list of strings. If you want a list of lists, you must convert each string to a list. This can be done easily with the `list()` function :

```py
map = [list(line) for line in map.splitlines()]
```